# Store SMS on phone

Tags: android, csv, sms

I am developing an android app for taking backup of sms on device.
I found that SMS information can be stored in CSV file.
Can anyone tell me the best methos to store sms information on phone ?

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to maintain a separate SMS information then use sqlite to store this message. It provide you greater flexibility in retrieving and searching content.

Comment: I want to store SMS and Restore it when neccesary.

Comment: Use sqlite database for your SMS

Comment: I want to store backup date-wise.while restoring user will choose which dated back to restore.I cannot achieve this in sqlite.